# ¿Como puedo rotar diferentes figuras independientemente?

Tags: java

Necesito girar varias figuras, pero se mueve todo el plano

Metodos de para girar que utilizo

```
this.graphics.transform(AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(Math.toRadians(this.direction),this.x, this.y));
```

Y el otro

```
this.graphics.rotate(Math.toRadians(this.direction),this.x, this.y);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si usa plain `Graphics`, eche al `Graphics2D` primero:

```
Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
```

Para rotar un entero `Graphics2D`:

```
g2d.rotate(Math.toRadians(degrees));
//dibujar forma / imagen (se rotará)
```

Para restablecer la rotación (para que solo gire una cosa):

```
AffineTransform old = g2d.getTransform();
g2d.rotate(Math.toRadians(degrees));
//dibujar forma / imagen (se rotará)
g2d.setTransform(old);
//las cosas que dibujas aquí no serán rotadas
```

Ejemplo:

```
class MyPanel extends JPanel {
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
        AffineTransform old = g2d.getTransform();
        g2d.rotate(Math.toRadians(degrees));
        //dibujar forma / imagen (se rotará)
        g2d.setTransform(old);
        //las cosas que dibujas aquí no serán rotadas
    }
}
```

Si desea convertir una nueva posición en una antigua AffineTransform, Se puede utilizar `rotate`, `scale` y `translate`. Mas información aquí: [Class AffineTransform](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html).

> También aquí tienes una [respuesta interesante](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html) sobre rotación...